# DisplayLink and USB cut off

Tags: usb, kernel, displaylink

I run Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T580.
The notebook is connected to an i-Tec DisplayLink docking station. All USB peripherals (mouse, keyboard, etc.) and 2 monitors (HDMI) are connected to the docking station.
Up to version 5.4.0.89 of the kernel everything worked without problems.
Since kernel version 5.4.0.90 I'm experimenting something like USB cut off.
With the latest versions (from 90 to 96) I'm experiencing something like USB cut off. Occasionally the monitors darken and mouse does not respond.
I tried to connect mouse directly to the notebook but it makes no difference.
Sounds like a problem related to the new kernels.
Anyone can help me? I have to keep kernel 5.4.0.89 and using it.
Thanks